# How to rename LVM volume?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, lvm

Is is possible to rename an LVM volume?

I would like to rename `local0` to `vm`

Device is `/dev/mapper/vgdata-local0`

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually nothing to do with MDADM (which handles software RAID).  It is a question about LVM (Logical Volume Manager), which is a a layer of abstraction over physical storage - often used on top of a raid device, but can be used on top of pretty much any block device.  (Not sure if you can change the tags to be more appropriate)

Anyway, The solution is to use lvrename.  For an unmounted partition (I don't know if it would work with a mounted one, I'd imagine not), issue the command

```
lvrename vgdata local0 vm
```

Comment: Remember to update boot configuration after this, or your system might not boot upon restart.